# Solving linear equation with max min function

Tags: optimization

For a particular problem, I got some equations of the form
$a = \min(1-b,0.9)$
$b = \max(\min(1-a,0.7)$, $\min(c, 0.8))$
$c = \max(\min(1-a,0.9)$, $\min(1-c, 0.9))
a,b,c \in [0,1]$
The system has a unique solution $a = 0.23333, b = 0.766666, c = 0.76666$.

Just wondering, how can I solve those equations in a general case.

Answer (score 1):

The system does not have a unique solution.  Here are some more, obtained via linearizing the constraints and solving a mixed integer linear programming problem:
\begin{matrix}
a & b & c\\
\hline
0.2 & 0.8 & 0.8 \\
0.3 & 0.7 & 0.7 \\
0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5
\end{matrix}